# How to get the location of user using observepoint API

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, api

I am looking for some help on how I can use the Observepoint API to get the location from where the Audit was created. I am using Django.

Using the example on https://docs.api.observepoint.com/v2/web-audits/w43h2it5WmM2srcC2

This is my current code:

```
payload = "{}"
headers = { 'authorization': "api_key " + API_KEY}
get_user_loc = 'https://api.observepoint.com/v2/web-audits/locations'
response_loc = requests.request("GET", get_user_loc, data=payload, 
headers=headers)
ping = response_loc.json()
print(type(ping[1]))
for x in ping:
   print(x["name"], " = ", x["label"])
```

This is giving me all the locations it has.

```
mountain  =  Direct - Oregon, US
west  =  Proxy - N. California, US
eastern  =  Proxy - N. Virginia, US
emea  =  Proxy - Dublin, Ireland
apac  =  Proxy - Tokyo, Japan
brazil  =  Proxy - Sao Paulo, Brazil
london  =  Proxy - London, England
germany  =  Proxy - Frankfurt, Germany
singapore  =  Proxy - Singapore
australia  =  Proxy - Sydney, Australia
```

How do I get the exact current location and match it to one of these?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the location containing the word `"Direct"`, you can do this so:

```
for x in ping:
   if "Direct" in x["label"]:
       print(x["name"], " = ", x["label"])
```

If you want to know your geolocation use [geoip](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable/)